# User input not storing in a variable

Tags: python

I'm a new computing teacher and I'm having some problems with this code. I'm trying to get my students to create a very simple game using while and if statements.

When I run this code it will not take my input of y or n it keeps coming up with an error. Any ideas why?

```
monsterHealth = 20
playerHealth = 50

while monsterHealth > 0:
    print ("The monster attacks you dealing 10 damage")
    global playerHealth
    playerHealth = playerHealth - 10

    playerDecision = input("Would you like to stay and fight? y/n")

    if playerDecision == y:
        print ("You attack the monster and do 5 damage")
    if playerDecision == n:
        print("You run away with your tail between your legs.")
        break


    if playerHealth <= 0:
        print ("You died......")
        break
    if monsterHealth <= 0:
        print ("You defeated the monster!")
        break
```

Comment: I expect more from a computer teacher.. please.. "y", "n"..

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code. Also please fix the obvious errors. I expect that a computing teacher would be able to do that.

Comment: You should read the error you are getting, it tells you what was wrong. If you really can't work it out, *post the error here* and we will explain it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are comparing `playerDecision` with a **variable** `y` and **variable** `n`.

You should change that to the **string** `"y"` and `"n"`:

```
if playerDecision == "y":
if playerDecision == "n":
```

Comment: Tank you very much I completely overlooked this! I've always been an IT teacher and have never had any formal Computer Science training so I'm still prone to making silly mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

The error you get is a NameError as the variable y is not defined.
What you really want to do is

```
if playerDecision == 'y':
    print ("You attack the monster and do 5 damage")
if playerDecision == 'n':
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer it was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
playerDecision = input("Would you like to stay and fight? y/n")

if playerDecision == 'y':  # <-- this should fix it. 
    print ("You attack the monster and do 5 damage")
if playerDecision == 'n':
    print("You run away with your tail between your legs.")
    break     

if playerHealth <= 0:
    print ("You died......")
    break   

if monsterHealth <= 0:
    print ("You defeated the monster!")
    break
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious why he is using a break? He is in a while loop; break is correct, and is not the problem.

Comment: I did not see a while loop in the program anywhere. Could be very obvious to you, but I have seen people using break for no reason.

Comment: @Mani: `while monsterHealth > 0:` <-- Didn't you see this?

Comment: @KevinGuan: Did you look at the original post?

Comment: I can imagine the while was looked over because the original post had code formatting errors.

Comment: @RvdK: Ah, okay. Mani, now Rvdk fixed it, so I suggest you edit your answer.